# What is the correct type to include in the ProducesResponseType attribute for an ASP.NET Core API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

In the somewhat contrived code snippet below I have created a controller method which forms part of a ASP.NET Core MVC API. The method is decorated with the `ProducesResponseType` attribute, is it correct to indicate the response type is a `Stream`, or should the response type be `FileStreamResult`?

```cs
[HttpPost("APIFunctionCall")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Stream), 200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> ProcessNewRequestAsync(Request request)
{
    FileStream fs = File.Open(request.Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)
    return returnValue = new FileStreamResult(fs, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/ms-word"));
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be `FileStream` or `FileStreamResult` instead I would say

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FileStreamResult), 200)]
```

Comment: Which of the two is best? Why would I choose to specify FileStreamResult rather than FileStream? If I were returning an ObjectResult I would specify the encapsulated type so should I prefer FileStream in this case too?

Comment: @EarlSven Well you are returning `FileStreamResult` though in essence it's a `FileStream`. So I would say `FileStream` makes more sense probably.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thanks!